# How to get the number of unread tweets of a user using twitter gem in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im using Twitter gem to retrieve all the tweets. But how do i get the unread tweets since i last logged in ?

```
 def twitter
    @twitter = Twitter.user_timeline('pallavi_shastry', :count => 10)
 end
```

Comment: I believe there's more than one twitter gem out there. Can you link to the one you are using?

Comment: https://github.com/sferik/twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter API doesn't have such an option for `user_timeline`. But, since you have to store your last login time anyway, you can store the last tweet ID you read and then get all tweets with IDs higher than that.

```
def twitter(username, last_tweet_id = nil)
  # this will display the latest 10 tweets if you
  # have never read the user's timeline before
  opts = last_tweet_id ? { :since_id => last_tweet_id } : { :count => 10 }

  Twitter.user_timeline(username, opts)
end
```

Then you can use the method this way:

```
# will get all tweets newer than 365677293978398720
@twitter = twitter('pallavi_shastry', 365677293978398720)

# will get 10 latest tweets
@twitter = twitter('pallavi_shastry')
```